# UsageError: Line magic function `%sql` not found

Tags: python, sqlite

`%reload_ext sql`
`%sql sqlite://`

The second line can't be compiled and the report says: UsageError: Line magic function `%sql` not found. With Python3.8, jupyter notebook.

Comment: try installing: `pip install ipython-sql`

Answer (score 3):

The issue was solved for me using conda to install "ipython-sql", NOT using PIP.

conda install -c conda-forge ipython-sql

Answer (score 2):

To load sql:

```
%load_ext sql
```

To connect SqlLite:

```
%sql sqlite://
```

Comment: I tried your solution here but i get this error " No module named 'sql'"