# UsageError: Line magic function `%%bigquery` not found

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to load data from a Big query table to pandas dataframe. I followed the syntax given in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-storage-python-pandas).
Unfortunately, I am getting the error below.

[image]

I read a stackoverflow solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63882681/usageerror-line-magic-function-sql-not-found), and followed its solution but I got this.

[image]

Then, I tried separating the code lines, but I get a new error `UsageError: Line magic function` %%bigquery `not found.`

[image]

I have been trying for a couple of hours to resolve this. Even restarting the kernel is not working. This works the very first time you run it but not if you run it twice. I have no clue what's going on. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved by removing the comments

```
#-----------------------
#Loading the bigquery ..
#-----------------------
```

and just retaining the `%%bigquery` magic syntax as shown below

```
%%bigquery personas_raw
SELECT * FROM `project-id.dataset.table`
```

Here is the screenshot of my testing using a sample public dataset **WITH COMMENTS**  and got the same error message  as your post.
[image]

And here is the screenshot of the same syntax when the comment is removed.
[image]

Comment: Sir - you are legend !! This works.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you have run:

```
%load_ext google.cloud.bigquery
```

in a separate cell.
(And don't put comments before the line with `%%bigquery` in it, as [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71304546/8565438) says.)