# Jupyter lab syntax error for the same %%bigquery command on the GCP environment

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, jupyter-lab

I am trying to fetch a BigQuery table as a Python dataframe in the GCP's Jupyter lab environment. It **worked perfectly fine** and also performed analysis on the dataframe. However, **after restarting the kernel**, I am **unable to recreate the df** from the same command. The following is the **error** I received.

```
# Loading data from BigQuery to Python as a dataframe

%%bigquery input
SELECT 
    * 
FROM dataset.table1

Error:
    
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_26547/1617235092.py", line 4
    SELECT *
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Alternatively**, I **tried** to run the same step by opening a **new notebook** on a BigQuery sample dataset and to my surprise, **it worked perfectly.**

```
%%bigquery input
SELECT 
    * 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.natality`
LIMIT 5
```

Unfortunately, I am unaware of how to share a reproducible code on the GCP platform, as I am fairly new. But, I would **love to hear your views** and understand the **cause of the issue/error**.

Comment: Did it not work on the newly created notebook, where you ran the public query ? I tried replicating on my side. It is working fine with me. You might need to re install the pre requisites when running bigquery, pandas etc etc to the notebook.

Comment: Also just to test can you changing the format to ```SELECT * FROM dataset.table1```

Comment: @NestorCenizaJr, thanks for the response. Unfortunately, the format change did not work either. Also, as you rightly mentioned, all the pre-requisite packages were loaded prior to running the code. 

Well, I ran the code on Jupyter Lab in GCP --> VertexAI --> Workbench -->Open JupyterLab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After banging my head for more than 4 hours, the reason for the error was simple. **Comments preceding the %%bigquery magic command are not allowed.** Remove those comments and re-run the code block.

The original answer was found in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71302290/usageerror-line-magic-function-bigquery-not-found). It was great learning.